# Plotly R : How to update style of lines without redrawing (local)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to locally draw dozens of lines in a shiny app. After the lines are drawn, I would like to be able to change their styles without redrawing?

In the example below, for simplicity, there are only 6 traces (lines). I would like to change the opacity of the first and third lines only, without redrawing anything :

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(mtcars, x=mpg, y=wt, group=carb)
style(p = last_plot(), opacity=0.1) #Only modifies first line & complains : You've referenced non-existent traces
style(p = last_plot(), opacity=0.1, traces = 3) #Does not work at all
Warning: You've referenced non-existent traces
Error in p$data[[max(traces)]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How to use style()?

I searched a lot but could not find any documentation

thanks for your help

regards

Answer (score 1):

I think `style()` is intended to work with something like that:

```
p <- plot_ly(x = seq(0, 8), y = rnorm(8), name = "Blue Trace") %>%
       add_trace(y = rnorm(8), name = "Orange Trace") %>% 
       add_trace(y = rnorm(8), name = "Green Trace")
p
pp <- style(p = last_plot(), opacity=0.1, traces = 1)
pp
ppp <- style(pp = last_plot(), opacity=0.1, traces = 2)
ppp
pppp <- style(ppp = last_plot(), opacity=0.1, traces = 3)
pppp
```

Comment: Thanks. Clearly your example produces 3 traces and my example above does not. In my case,I have to draw lots of lines at once using a data.frame. If I add them with add_trace(), it would be super slow. So I'm still looking for a solution that can work with my initial example above. Funny that style() is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps? You should be able to jump into any of the traces and modify / add any property fairly quickly.

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x=mpg, y=wt, group=carb)
p <- plotly_build(p)
p$data[[1]]$opacity = 0.1
p$data[[3]]$opacity = 0.1

p
```

Comment: Looks fine. Internally, does this redraw the whole thing or just merely modifies existing traces? Since it's a lightweight example, difficult to tell.

Comment: It modifies data / properties of existing traces. But for the chart to actually update on screen, you'll have to plot it again. The object you get from plotly build is essentially a list that is passed to plotly.js internally. So you'll have to refresh the actual plot for the changes to be seen. At least that's how I understand it.